# How do I use the IP address instead of hostname in Eureka?

Tags: docker, netflix-eureka

I need to tell a Eureka client running in Docker to use the host's IP to register its service. I used the below, but it doesn't work.

```
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

The service registered in Eureka is the container ID.

Answer (score -1):

try to run docker container in host mode like this:

```
docker run --net=host ...
```